# Leaving and re-entering Stinking Cloud

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The spell [*stinking cloud*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stinking-cloud) says

> This condition [nauseated] lasts as long as the creature is in the cloud and for 1d4+1 rounds after it leaves.

So, here's the scenario: A creature is in the area of a *stinking cloud* and fails the saving throw. Chased by its enemies, the creature leaves the *cloud*'s area, but then its enemies chase it back into the *cloud*'s area.

Does the "clock" reset as far as the nausea is concerned? Do you continue to count down the 1d4+1 rounds? Does he need to make Fort saves while he's nauseated?

Does this change if the person steps out and steps back in the same turn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clock does reset. The creature is nauseated for the duration of the time he is in the fog cloud, whether that's its initial exposure or a later re-entry into the cloud. From the spell:

> This condition lasts as long as the creature is in the cloud and for 1d4+1 rounds after it leaves.

The creature who failed its save is nauseated any time it is in the cloud. Each time it leaves the cloud, the countdown beings. Essentially, it must be free from exposure to the cloud for 1d4+1 rounds before the nausea ends.

A creature does not continue to make fortitude saves once it is nauseated. The spell specifies that the only time it continues to make saves is if it made the initial save but continues to stay in the cloud. If it does not make a new save each time it enters the cloud, it means that once it fails one save against the cloud it is considered as having failed for the duration of that cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Both should be in effect, although the penalty only applies once. If for instance the second time leaving, the creature has a shorter time than from the initial application, the longer one should apply.